# Control word/text break on React Native <Text> element

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to control the word-break behaviour for text within a Text component? With a multiple-line Text component on iOS it automatically breaks the text where there are word breaks (I haven't checked android yet, but I'd need it to work there too). I was hoping to change that behaviour to break on the per-character level, like you can do this CSS rule:

```
word-break: break-all;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an Android-only [textbreakstrategy](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text#textbreakstrategy) property for Text components that allows some control on how a text should be split. The property values map to Android's native [android:breakStrategy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:breakStrategy) values.

This property does not seem to translate to iOS though.

Otherwise, if you have preknowledge about the Text value, you could indicate text split with a [Soft Hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen)

```
<Text>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbb&shy;CCCCC.</Text>
```

This would render as:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbb-
CCCCC.
```

If neither suffice, I suppose this is beyond the capabilities of a Text component and you may have to revert to another component. Maybe one that renders simple html.

Comment: Thanks @tvanlaehoven! I suspected as much.

Answer (score 2):

transform `<text>str</text>` to `<View><text>s</text><text>t</text><text>r</text></View>` by using split & map!

```js
export default class PageCard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tail: false,
            longWord: 'longWord longWord bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb longWord longWord longWord',
            longWordTail: ' longWord longWord longWord bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb longWord longWord longWord',
            longWordTail2: ' longWord longWord bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb longWord longWord longWord',
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 60, paddingHorizontal: 10}}>
                
                <View style={Styles.breakWordWrap}>
                    <Text numberOfLines={2} ellipsizeMode="tail" style={Styles.breakWord}>
                        {this.state.longWord}
                    </Text>
                </View>

                <View style={Styles.breakWordWrap}>
                    {
                        this.breakWord(this.state.longWord)
                    }
                </View>

                <View style={[Styles.breakWordWrap, Styles.breakWordWrapTail]}>
                    {
                        this.breakWord(this.state.longWordTail)
                    }
                </View>

                <View style={[Styles.breakWordWrap, Styles.breakWordWrapTail]}>
                    {
                        this.breakWord(this.state.longWordTail, true)
                    }
                </View>

                {/*<View style={[Styles.breakWordWrap, Styles.breakWordWrapTail]}>*/}
                {/*    {*/}
                {/*        this.breakWord(this.state.longWordTail2, true)*/}
                {/*    }*/}
                {/*</View>*/}

            </ScrollView>
        )
    }

    breakWord = (str = '', tail = false) => {
        let strArr = (tail ? str + ' ' : str).split('');
        return strArr.map((item, index) => tail && strArr.length === index + 1 ?
            <Text key={item + index} style={[Styles.breakWord, Styles.breakWordTail, !this.state.tail && Styles.breakWordTailHide]}>...</Text> :
            (tail && strArr.length === index + 2 ? <Text key={item + index} style={[Styles.breakWord]} onLayout={this.breakWordLast}>{item}</Text>
                : <Text key={item + index} style={[Styles.breakWord]}>{item}</Text>)
        );

    }

    breakWordLast = (e) => {
        console.log(e.nativeEvent.layout)
        if (e.nativeEvent.layout.y > 50) {
            this.setState({
                tail: true
            })
        }
    }

}
```

```css
const Styles = {
    box: {
        marginTop: 10,
    },
    title: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: '#333',
        textAlign: 'center'
    },
    breakWordWrap: {
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        // not
        borderWidth: 1,
        marginTop: 30,
    },
    breakWordWrapTail: {
        position: 'relative',
        height: 50,
        overflow: 'hidden'
    },
    breakWord: {
        lineHeight: 25
    },
    breakWordTail: {
        position: 'absolute',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        height: 25
    },
    breakWordTailHide: {
        opacity: 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is the possibility with following code

`<Text style={{ flexShrink: 1 }}>`

Answer (score 0):

Try add `flexWrap: "wrap"` to the style of the Text component

Example:

**Code**

```js
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Text style={styles.text}>{text}</Text>
</View>
```

**Style**

```js
export default StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      alignItems: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    width: 0,
    flexGrow: 1,
    flex: 1,
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But that still breaks on the end of the words, not at the specific character.

Comment: I just update the post above. Maybe it helpful for you. Don't forget to upvote my vote ^.^

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I'm not being clear. I need it to break on a specific character, not on the word. e.g. If the text is "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbCCCCC" and the available width on the screen can fit the a's and the b's, but not the C's, it would break the second word where the C's begin. Your updated code doesn't do this.